# Extract json array data using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, geocode, reversegeocodelocation

I would like to obtain the formatted_address from the json data returned from the following query string by using javascript.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
    //use ajax and json
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+sessionStorage.latitude+","+sessionStorage.longitude+"&sensor=true",
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var address = response.Result;
            var error = response.Error;

            if (address != null) {
                alert("Found current location: " + address.formatted_address);
                sessionStorage.currentAddress = address.formatted_address;
                return;
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            errorConnection();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried getting formatted_address but it return undefined.

Comment: `var address = response.results[0];` see my answer for more details

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get formatted address like this (Ajax Success)

```
   success: function (results) {
        var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
              alert(JSON.stringify(address));
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previous response only fixed the AJAX request- 
specifying contentType on a request is not required and has no impact - this is controlled by the server.

jQuery already will parse the request to an object, calling `JSON.stringify` on the response was causing the object to be parsed into a JSON formatted string, removing that line resolved the issue. Also specifying dataType didn't seem to be necessary.

It's worth noting that you're passing lat, and lng arguments to the function but not using them - I'd suggest either adding a lines like:

```
lat = lat || sessionStorage.latitude; 
lng = lng || sessionStorage.longitude;
```

Below should be a solution complete with my suggestions:

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
    lat = lat || sessionStorage.latitude;
    lng = lng || sessionStorage.longitude;

    jsondata = {};
    //use ajax and json
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + sessionStorage.latitude + "," + sessionStorage.longitude + "&sensor=true",
        data: jsondata,

        success: function (response) {

            var address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
            var error = response.Error;
            if (address != null) {
                alert("Found current location: " + address);
                sessionStorage.currentAddress = address;
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            errorConnection();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I only resolved the ajax issue with my answer previously - I've updated my answer to fix the remaining problems

Comment: Thank you Brian for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just changed the success function with this, you will get all the formatted address

```
success: function (response) {
    var address = response.results;
    var error = response.error; //write exact word of the "error" which you get in response

    if(address.length > 0) {
        for(i=0; i<address.length; i++) {
            console.log("Found current location: " + address[i].formatted_address);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to fix:

apparently you don't have to post data as you're making a `GET` request.

I rewrote your code to take the parameters from `lat` and `lng` in order to test it easily.

`response` is an object that contains an array of `results` objects (lowercase `r` plural). Each object contains a `formatted_address` property.

Most likely you'll want to fetch the first one:

`response.results[0].formatted_address`

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
    //use ajax and json
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Found current location: " + response.results[0].formatted_address);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

To try it:

```
getReverseGeocodingData(44.4647452,7.3553838);
```

Outputs:

`Found current location: Via Pasubio, 34, 12025 Dronero CN, Italia`

Comment: Thank you Paolo for your help.